# Replace "flatline" repeated data in Pandas series with nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have hourly time series data stored in a pandas series.  Similar to this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019', end='1/2/2019', freq='H')
data = np.random.uniform(180,182,size=(len(date_rng)))

timeseries = pd.Series(data, index=date_rng)
timeseries.iloc[4:12] = 181.911
```

At three decimal places, it is highly unlikely the data will be exactly the same for more than, say, 3 hours in a row.  When this flatlining occurs, it indicates an issue with the sensor.  So I want to detect repeated data and replace it with nan values (i.e., detect the repeated values 181.911 in the above and replace with nan)

I assume I can iterate over the time series and detect/replace that way, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: look into `pandas.Series.rolling`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `diff`, but the first occurrence retain in the series.

```
timeseries.where(timeseries.diff(1)!=0.0,np.nan)

2019-01-01 00:00:00    180.539278
2019-01-01 01:00:00    181.509729
2019-01-01 02:00:00    180.740326
2019-01-01 03:00:00    181.736425
2019-01-01 04:00:00    181.911000
2019-01-01 05:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 06:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 07:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 08:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 09:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 10:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 11:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 12:00:00    180.093216
2019-01-01 13:00:00    180.623440
```

First occurrence also can be removed using `diff(-1)` and `diff(1)`:

```
np.c_[timeseries.where(timeseries.diff(-1)!=0.0,np.nan), timeseries.where(timeseries.diff(1)!=0.0,np.nan)].mean(axis=1)
```

It works when repetitions are sequential in series.

Comment: Thanks, this works well for checking two values, but not say 3 or more in a row, which would be more indicative of faulty flatlined data

Answer (score 0):

With following reasonably efficient function one can choose the minimum number of repeated values to consider as flatline:

```py
import numpy as np

def remove_flatlines(ts, threshold):
    # get start and end indices of each flatline as an n x 2 array
    isflat = np.concatenate(([False], np.isclose(ts.diff(), 0), [False]))
    isedge = isflat[1:] != isflat[:-1]
    flatrange = np.where(isedge)[0].reshape(-1, 2)
    # include also first value of each flatline
    flatrange[:, 0] -= 1

    # remove flatlines with at least threshold number of equal values
    ts = ts.copy()
    for j in range(len(flatrange)):
        if flatrange[j][1] - flatrange[j][0] >= threshold:
            ts.iloc[flatrange[j][0]:flatrange[j][1]] = np.nan
    return ts
```

Applied to example:

```py
remove_flatlines(timeseries, threshold=3)

2019-01-01 00:00:00    181.447940
2019-01-01 01:00:00    180.142692
2019-01-01 02:00:00    180.994674
2019-01-01 03:00:00    180.116489
2019-01-01 04:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 05:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 06:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 07:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 08:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 09:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 10:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 11:00:00           NaN
2019-01-01 12:00:00    180.972644
2019-01-01 13:00:00    181.969759
2019-01-01 14:00:00    181.008693
2019-01-01 15:00:00    180.769328
2019-01-01 16:00:00    180.576061
2019-01-01 17:00:00    181.562315
2019-01-01 18:00:00    181.978567
2019-01-01 19:00:00    181.928330
2019-01-01 20:00:00    180.773995
2019-01-01 21:00:00    180.475290
2019-01-01 22:00:00    181.460028
2019-01-01 23:00:00    180.220693
2019-01-02 00:00:00    181.630176
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```