# How to detect horizontal line (stagnation) in data?

Tags: python, math, scipy, data-science

How can I detect horizontal lines in my data in python?

I have used function `scipy.signal.find_peaks()` to find local minima and maxima. I can use that to separate ascending and descending parts. But I need to isolate the peaks from the flat line (marked with red circes in image).

What method should I use? Is there any library that could do that?

[image: Graph with red markers around flat horizontal lines]

Comment: Calculate a differential. But this is non-reproducible with no code and no data.

Comment: When we look at something like that and say "There's bumps separated by flat parts," we are essentially constructing a piecewise continuous model mentally. A strong approach would be to directly replicate that process in a formal model -- ideally you would optimize over both the locations of the break points and the parameters for each piece. Finding the break points is probably the harder part of the problem. See "Nonlinear Regression" by Seber & Wild (1989), chapter 9, "Multiphase and spline regressions", for some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write some algorithm to find the differences between points in the graph.

[pandas.DataFrame.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) is useful

```py
difference = df.diff(periods=-1)
```

Above line gets you the difference between each row and the next

Use some threshold number, lets say 0.1.

```py
threshold = 0.1
```

Check if the difference between points is > threshold

If difference < threshold, then continue on the next point
until diff > threshold. (this means you're at the end of that flat line)

Continue looping through all your data until all flat lines have been discovered. Then do whatever operations with that data.

Something like this: (probably won't work, basically pseudocode)

```py
flat_lines = []
for point in difference:
    if difference <= threshold:
        #Change in point a to point b is less than 0.1
        #start = index of start of flat line
        flat_lines.append(start)
        continue
    elif difference > threshold:
        #End of flatline
        #store whatever data you need
        #end= index of endof flat line
        flat_lines.append(end)
        continue
```

These posts may also help:
[A simple algorithm to detect flat segments in noisy signals](https://dracodoc.wordpress.com/2014/07/21/a-simple-algorithm-to-detect-flat-segments-in-noisy-signals/)

[Replace "flatline" repeated data in Pandas series with nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921186/replace-flatline-repeated-data-in-pandas-series-with-nan)